# Rails - using JSON for a timeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, routes, timeline

I've used json_builder to generate the JSON file needed for the timeline from timeline.verite.co as it needs to be in a specific format. However, when I load the page, it gets stuck with a white background and a loading gif. It works if I give it a link to some sample data, but not the generated data for the user. The html page (users/1/events) works fine. Anyone have any idea why? I've run out of ideas now!!

UPDATE:

I got the JS to link to a static file with the pasted contents of the JSON from users/1/events.json, and it works fine. So I'm assuming the problem is that the page is blank when the JS tries to fetch it, and only get populated when you actually go to that URL. How do I get around this?

Generated JSON file (got by going to /users/1/events.json):

```
{
  "timeline": {
    "headline": "Emily",
    "type": "default",
    "text": "A Timeline",
    "startDate": "1922,10,30",
    "date": [
      {
        "startDate": "2012,11,17",
        "endDate": "2012,11,17",
        "headline": "My Birthday",
        "text": "This is my birthday",
        "asset": {
          "media": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dePMU8R131s",
          "credit": "",
          "caption": "Happy Birthday"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Required syntax:

```
{
    "timeline":
    {
        "headline":"Stuff People Say",
        "type":"default",
        "text":"People say stuff",
        "startDate":"2012,1,26",
        "date": [
            {
                "startDate":"2012,1,26",
                "endDate":"2012,1,27",
                "headline":"Stuff Politicians Say",
                "text":"<p>In true political fashion, his character rattles off common jargon heard from people running for office.</p>",
                "asset":
                {
                    "media":"http://youtu.be/u4XpeU9erbg",
                    "credit":"",
                    "caption":""
                }
            },
            {
                "startDate":"2012,1,10",
                "headline":"Stuff Nobody Says",
                "text":"<p>Have you ever heard someone say “can I burn a copy of your Nickelback CD?” or “my Bazooka gum still has flavor!” Nobody says that.</p>",
                "asset":
                {
                    "media":"http://youtu.be/f-x8t0JOnVw",
                    "credit":"",
                    "caption":""
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

controller (relevant bits):

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json, :html

def myevents
    @events = current_user.events
    respond_with @users
  end

end
```

routes:

```
resources :events do
    member do
      get 'myevents'
    end
  end

match 'users/:id/events' => 'events#myevents'
```

JS to call timeline:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "/js/storyjs-embed.js" %>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                createStoryJS({
                    type:       'timeline',
                    width:      '800',
                    height:     '600',
                    source:     '/users/<%= current_user.id %>/events.json',
                    embed_id:   'my-timeline'
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: instead of `source: '/users/<%= current_user.id %>/events.json'`, use routes helpers

Comment: sorry, i'm pretty new to rails, how would I do that? When I check the source code, that link is pointing to the right place, but it isn't finding the data at that link for some reason. That's what I've narrowed the problem down to now. Is the data not generated until I specifically go to that link, and not when the JS tries to fetch the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the end, the js for the form wasn't reading the JSON file properly. I needed to add a callback.

Comment: hey Emily, can you share how you created the json, i'm having issues while doing date and nesting. i'm also using timeline js in my project and there's a lot of nesting invloved. Appreciate your help

Comment: Everything I did to create the json is in the original question. I used the gem json_builder to generate the json needed for the timeline, and put the source as:  source:     '/users/<%= current_user.id %>/events.json?callback' - it didn't work without the callback.